# TamperMonkey set strange cookies

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I see some strange cookies (see screenshot below) when using TamperMonkey. It's conflicting with one of the website I use.

They starts with TM_ and have extension UUID in the content so I am assuming TamperMonkey is creating them.

### Specifications

- Chrome Dev x64 Latest
- TM:  Beta Latest
- OS: Windows 11 x64 Latest

[image: 2022-06-01_194303]